# Cannot read property 'split' of undefined - in LWC js

Tags: lightning-web-components, split, js, lightning-record-page

I have the following LWC, when I try to add on my lightning record page got some error like, cannot read property of split.

[image]

js:

```
import { LightningElement, api, track } from 'lwc';
    export default class CustomRecordDetail extends LightningElement {
     @track fieldArray;
        connectedCallback()
         {
            if(this.fields !== null && typeof this.fields !== undefined && this.fields !== '')
            {
                this.fieldArray = this.fields.split(",");
            }
    }
    }
```

html :

```
<template>
    <div class="slds-card">
        <div class="slds-grid slds-page-header forceRelatedListCardHeader">
            <header class="slds-media slds-media_center slds-has-flexi-truncate">
                <div class="slds-media__figure"> 
                     <lightning-icon icon-name={icon} size={size} alternative-text="Connected">
                    </lightning-icon>     
                </div>
                <div class="slds-media__body">
                    <h2 class="slds-card__header-title slds-text-title_bold"> {title} </h2>
                </div>
            </header>
        </div>
       
                <div class="slds-media__body">
                    <div class="slds-p-left_medium">

                    <lightning-record-form
                    record-id={recordId}
                    fields={fieldArray}>
                    </lightning-record-form>
                </div>
                </div>
       </div>
```

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>50.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
    </targets>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage">
            <property name="fields" type="string"/>
            </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Comment: Where is `this.fields` defined/initialized? It is used in the connectedCallback. I see you have a tracked property, `fieldArray` but this would be referenced as `this.fieldArray` not `this.fields`.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you really want should be achievable by just

```
if(this.fields) {
   this.fieldArray = this.fields.split(",");
}
```

Can you give it a try and let us know if you stop receiving the error?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `typeof` in JS. That returns a string value. [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

So if you check `typeof this.fields !== "undefined"`, then it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

import { LightningElement, api, track } from 'lwc';
export default class CustomRecordDetail extends LightningElement {
@track fieldArray;
@track fields="How are you doing today?";
connectedCallback()
{
if(!this.fields)
{
this.fieldArray = this.fields.split(" ");
}
}
}

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have not declared the variable '**fields**' in your js file on which you are performing the '**split**' operation, Please declare and initialize the variable and then try.

Answer (score -2):

```
@track fieldArray=[]; // Array to store a value
connectedCallback() {
    if(this.fields !== null && typeof this.fields !== undefined && this.fields !== ''){
        this.fieldArray = this.fields.split(",");
    }
```

Comment: Is this really an answer to your question, or is it something you meant to add to your question by making an edit?